# How to switch numbers in a vector

Tags: vectors

This question is extremely hard to explain, so the title is probably misleading.

I have a vector of (0,x,y), (or (x,0,y), (x,y,0), basically any combination), and I need a vector of (1,0,0) (or (0,1,0), (0,0,1), or least any two known outcome numbers). Also, x and y are always < 0.

I need an equation that doesn't involve picking apart the vector, applying equations to each of the numbers, and putting it back together again. I already have a solution like that, but the purpose I am trying to use it for won't allow that.

For example, if you take -5 (or any negative number) and 0 in the equation ((x+1)/(|x+1|)+1)/2 where x is < 0.

((-5+1)/(|-5+1|)+1)/2 = 0. ((0+1)/(|0+1|)+1)/2 = 1

Or if you take 0 and 1 in the equation (x-1)*-1

(x-1)*-1 = 1. (1-1)*-1 = 0.

How can I achieve this same result using only vector operations?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please display all your equations with MathJax. It is easier to read that way.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You are given a vector $\langle x, y, z\rangle$ where exactly one element is zero, and you would like some sort of computationally nice function which outputs a vector which indicates where the input was 0, i.e. $\langle I(x=0), I(y=0), I(z=0)\rangle$.

Comment: Yep, it's better asked like this user326210. I have an additional question why can't it be done component per component ? What operations on vectors are we allowed to use ?

Comment: What is the context of "*picking apart the vector, applying equations to each of the numbers, and putting it back together again*"? eg taking the norm $||v||$ is clear as notation without indexing each element, but the naive definition of the norm still uses the components.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ always integers, or can they be any real number? (I know you've said they're negative.)

Comment: user326210, you are exactly correct., and x and y are pretty much almost always going to be non-integers. (Working in a 3D environment, which would make it almost impossible to have an integer, but it simplified the explanation)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which functions you're allowed, but if you have a function which normalizes nonzero vectors (and keeps the zero vector the same):

$$\mathsf{unit}(\vec{v}) = \begin{cases}\vec{v}/||\vec{v}|| & \vec{v}\neq \vec{0}\\\vec{0} & \vec{v} = \vec 0\end{cases}$$

then you can define

$\mathsf{indicate}(\vec{v}) \equiv \mathsf{unit}\left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}\right) + \mathsf{unit}\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}\right) + \mathsf{unit}\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}\right)$.

---

Edit: Alternatively, perhaps you could use exponentiation:

$$\mathsf{indicate}(\vec{v}) \equiv 0^{\vec{v}}$$.

Comment: The only functions allowed are the more basic functions (dot product, cross product, vector addition/subtraction, integer multiplication/division on a vector, and some others I can't think of off the top of my head right now.) So any form of (for lack of a better term) "if statement" cannot be done.

Comment: How about exponentiation? $\mathsf{indicate}(\vec{v}) = 0^\vec{v}$

Comment: Sadly no, but vector projection is a thing

Comment: @Bedrockbreaker, Can you explain more about what your application is, and why disassembling the vector and reassembling it won't work?

Comment: Basically, i'm playing minecraft. *yeah*. Something adds stuff that adds spells which use vectors. The only issue is the person who added it, likes throwing wrenches into your plans. So.... No if statements, no really advanced stuff, just pure math. There is a limited amount of space in my spell and disassembling the vector takes up too much space.

Comment: @Bedrockbreaker Neat! Do you think it's possible to find a more efficient way to take apart the vector so it fits in the spell? For example using projection $\vec{v}\cdot \langle 0, 0, 1\rangle$?   Also what's going to happen to the output of your function---something else is going to check which value is 1?

Comment: Not exactly, The equation I use takes up over half the space, and makes it really hard to fit anything at all in there that would be useful. So far, It takes the relative vector of the player the raycast and then finds the axis which has the largest difference. Then, it would run through which the equation I'm trying to find which would then be projected onto the original relative vector, which would break a line of blocks starting at the raycast towards my player.

Comment: Can you clarify some more? It sounds like the player is at some point $P$, and is pointing at some point $Q$. There are blocks in space arranged in a rigid grid aligned with the coordinate axes. When you point, you want to "snap" the vector $\vec{PQ}$ to a vector $\vec{R}$ which is most similar to it but parallel to one of the coordinate axes. Then you want to break all blocks starting at point $Q$ and moving in the $-\vec{R}$ direction ("toward the player"). Is that right?

Comment: That is exactly what I want.

Comment: Great! I'm not exactly sure what "pure math" stuff you have available. If you have vectors, do you have tools like trig functions, dot product, matrix multiplication, computing the norm/length of a vector, multiplying a vector by a number, normalizing a vector to length 1, squaring every entry in a vector?

Comment: For example, here is a cool hack: if you could take the vector $\vec{PQ}$ and raise every entry to a large odd power (say, 7), the resulting vector would basically be $\vec{R}$, aligned with one of the coordinate axes. The larger the power, the more aligned the vector would be. You could then normalize the vector to make it a reasonable length.

Comment: Raising a vector sadly isn't a thing, and neither is matrix multiplication. But everything else you said in that list was in there

Comment: @Bedrockbreaker Then, what if: start with vector $\vec{PQ}$. Let $x = \mathtt{dot}(\vec{PQ}, \langle 1,0,0\rangle)^7$, $y = \mathtt{dot}(\vec{PQ}, \langle 0,1,0\rangle)^7$, $z = \mathtt{dot}(\vec{PQ}, \langle 0,0,1\rangle)^7$. Return a new vector $\vec{R} = \mathtt{normalize}(\langle x, y, z\rangle)$. This implements the entire function using only dot product, normalization, and raising numbers (not vectors) to powers. Would that fit? Do you have a built-in function to access a component of a vector?

Comment: If you can get components of a vector, you can do this shorter: $\vec{R} =\mathtt{normalize}\left(\mathtt{vector}\left[\mathtt{pow}(\mathtt{getx}(\vec{PQ}), C), \mathtt{pow}(\mathtt{gety}(\vec{PQ}), C), \mathtt{pow}(\mathtt{getz}(\vec{PQ}), C) \right]\right)$ where $C$ is the constant 7 (or some larger odd number).

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been posting, been away at some science camp thingy. Anyways, the first solution looks like it could work. I will try it tomorrow and return the results.